# Qpid receiver on Azure EventHub

Tags: java, azure, amqp, azure-eventhub, qpid

I have already working application based on Azure EventHub. Now I need write java receiver that connects to the existing infrastructure. 
Existing configuration:

Event Hub > *SomeName* > Consumer Group > *SomeGroupName*

In the administrative console I cannot see any QUEUE or TOPIC definitions. Analyzing working c# code I can see that hub-name + group-name is enough to connect.

I have reconstructed url that allows me to connect over java (and connection works so far).

amqps://SomeName.servicebus.windows.net

So my questions:

1) When instead of queue /topic I specify group-name then I get exception `The messaging entity 'sb://SomeName.servicebus.windows.net/SomeGroupName' could not be found.` What is the model used there instead of queue/topic?

2) How to work with such infrastructure from Apache-qpid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The greatest hint for resolve the question gave me following link: http://theitjourney.blogspot.com/2015/12/sendreceive-messages-using-amqp-in-java.html

So No queue neither topic in this model. You need to connect to specific provider and specify correct EventHub as following:

`application.properties`:

```
connectionfactory.SBCF=amqps://<PolicyName>:<PolicyKey>@<DomainName>.servicebus.windows.net
queue.EventHub=<EventHubName>/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/0
```

Where: 
[image]

After that following code allowed me to create MessageConsumer:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
               "org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, 
    getClass().getResource("/application.properties").toString());
Context context = null;

context = new InitialContext(env);
// Look up ConnectionFactory 
ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("SBCF");
Destination queue = (Destination) context.lookup("EventHub");

// Create Connection
Connection connection = cf.createConnection();

// Create receiver-side Session, MessageConsumer
Session receiveSession = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
MessageConsumer receiver = receiveSession.createConsumer(queue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Event Hub created in the old portal or one created using the new portal?

EventHub is not a Message Bus, so there are no Queues or Topics, that is correct.

The consumer group is not a part of the address. The address is build using the namespace and the name of the eventhub in that namespace.

So the address becomes:

```
sb://SomeNameSpaceName.servicebus.windows.net/SomeEventHubName
```

Can you post the c# code you've analyzed? Since you have an already working application maybe we can workout the differences that prevents it from working now.